# How to reorganise data in a binary file in C?

Tags: c, file, binary

I have a binary file which contains data in 128-byte blocks that are spread across the file. Each block starts with a `char` array of length `8`.

How do I reorganize the data in this binary file such that all 128-byte blocks are ordered sequentially and that there is no unused space between these blocks?

Unused/unallocated space is just represented by `0` in this file and strings are null terminated.

I'm quite lost.

Comment: Can you show us some example of what you have and what you want?

Comment: Read it, write a temp file in the desired format, delete the original file, rename the temp file.

Comment: "*that are spread across the file*" please more precisely explain what this means.

Comment: "*are ordered sequentially*" please more precisely explain what this means.

Comment: So in the binary file, the data blocks may start at random offsets, like 0, 500, 648, etc. This is what I mean by blocks being "spread across the file".

When I say I want these blocks to be "ordered sequentially", I mean that the first byte in the file they start at are 0, 128, 256, etc.

Comment: Would there be zeros inside a "*128-byte block*"?

Comment: No there would not

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not a complete specification, e.g.:

```
 - what is unused space?
 - do the char arrays contain string terminator or not?
 - is the file small enough to read into memory, or is it large?
```

So I cannot write it to you. However you can program it easily if you follow these instructions:

```
1. Build a list of pointers to the used 128 bytes blocks.
2. Sort that list.
3. You can now overwrite the file looping through the ordered list of pointers.
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Unused/unallocated space is just represented by 0 in this file and strings are null terminated. The file is small enough to be read into memory.